# Azure AD B2C Signup custompolicy form for local accounts missing inputs

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using custom policies which are based on the [Azure B2C's starter pack for local accounts](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/main/LocalAccounts).

When signing up a new user I am not being presented with a firstName input, despite having one defined:

[image]

My SignUporSignin policy is as follows:

```
  <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
    <Endpoints>
      <!--points to refresh token journey when app makes refresh token request-->
      <Endpoint Id="Token" UserJourneyReferenceId="RedeemRefreshToken" />
      <Endpoint Id="UserInfo" UserJourneyReferenceId="UserInfoJourney" />
    </Endpoints>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="correlationId" DefaultValue="{Context:CorrelationId}" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName"/>
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
```

The claim type for givenName is as follows:

```
      <ClaimType Id="givenName">
        <DisplayName>Given Name</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
          <Protocol Name="OAuth2" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
          <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
          <Protocol Name="SAML2" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname" />
        </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
        <UserHelpText>Your given name (also known as first name).</UserHelpText>
        <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
      </ClaimType>
```

**How do I have the other inputs such as givenName showup?**

Comment: What claims have you defined in the self-asserted profile for the signup step?

Comment: I'm assuming that these claims are defined within the `<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">` 

If so, i have only one input claim there: `<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />`

Comment: What about DisplayClaims or OutputClaims?

Comment: there are no DisplayClaims but OutputClaims do include the following:`            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />`

Comment: Ok.. in that case it should get displayed :\ If there are no DisplayClaims defined, then the ones in OutputClaims get rendered, as long as they have a UserInputType.

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm that in "LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail", you have these lines:

```
<!-- Optional claims, to be collected from the user -->
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
```

Note that the image shows you are missing the first two.